# Time taken for withColumn in spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to find the time associated with the following operation in spark

```
df = df.withColumn(RANK, functions.rank().over(Window.partitionBy(partitionColumnsList.get(i))
                                .orderBy(functions.desc(orderingColumn))));
```

Something like this won't work due to lazy execution:-

```
 long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
 df = df.withColumn(RANK, functions.rank().over(Window.partitionBy(partitionColumnsList.get(i))
                                          .orderBy(functions.desc(orderingColumn))));
 long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("Time taken: "+(endTime-startTime));
```

I tried using spark UI logs, but they have stage-wise info only. I would need to have a separate action for this and we don't want to have many actions in our code.

For map partitions, I have used accumulators to calculate time, but here I don't I can use it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried using spark.time {<invoke your methods>}

Comment: Yes, but it gives similar results to my second code snippet. It doesn't show the true time.

Comment: i got it .. inside spark.time they are doing same thing in your second code snippet.